# "clock_t clock()" in global namespace

Tags: c++, clock

That causes a compilation error under linux (Ubuntu 16.04.2) with GCC (gcc 6.3.0 / libstdc++6) because `pthread.h` (included by `iostream`) has a global function called `clock`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

struct clock {};

int main()
{
    clock c;
    (void)c;
}

// Error:

main.cpp:37:7: error: ‘template<class duration_tt> struct clock’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
 class clock
       ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/pthread.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/time.h:189:16: note: previous declaration ‘clock_t clock()’
 extern clock_t clock (void) __THROW;
```

Shouldn't every name introduced by the standard library be inside a namespace?

Comment: What platform? What version of gcc? What version of libstdc++?

Comment: You probably ought to fret a bit about `class` appearing in a C header file.  Cut-and-paste accident, perhaps.

Comment: _"Shouldn't every name introduced by the standard library be inside a namespace?"_ Yes. If that name was introduced by **C++** standard library.

Comment: @HansPassant It's not a C header file. In a C++ source code file.

Comment: *"Shouldn't every name introduced by the standard library be inside a namespace?"* Not necessarily. `cstddef` for example puts type aliases in both `std` and the global namespace. This is a good reason to always use a namespace for your own code (except, obviously, for `main()`).

Comment: "Shouldn't every name ..." - maybe. But, *should* and *does* are two very different things.

Comment: I have the same problem when including just <chrono>. That header includes <ctime> which includes <time.h> which defines clock_t  and clock in global namespace. I'd like to know if this legal wrt the standard, or that it is a bug of this distribution? https://wandbox.org/permlink/lSkx4wY0vxbsBDqK